# How to retrieve database connection from Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento

One of our customer is in a unfortunate situation, his actual hosting provider is not providing the credentials to access the local files, he only has a Magento login with admin/store-manager rights or something like this.

We need to either export the products into a SQL file or access the database login, we cannot open the relative .xml file as we do not have access to the server files. Any idea on how to dump the database except exporting it as CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel

```
System ->Tools -> Backups
```

Click on Database Backup. After Finish the process Click on link available in `Download` column

Comment: is this methong accessible from within magento or I need to access it from server side software such as plesk/cpanel?